# Texturing a wall with Joint Compound

Tags: walls

[image: Texturing an already painting wall with joint compound.]
How can I fix this problem of the joint compound cracking on me, without starting all over?
I am using a Premixed Ready to use. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you moisten the wall before applying?

Comment: **No I did not.If I were to apply a another coat over it that a lot thinner, would that help my problem some? How thin do I need it to be to finish the rest of the wall?**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the mix was a bit dry and a heavy knock down, if there is not enough moisture in the mud or the wall was not prepped well this happens. It is hard to tell is this a patch? If doing an entire area after taping and sanding I usually wipe the wall with a damp towel to remove dust, when I have large jobs done my mud slinger says why wast the time just add water (he is way faster than I am and his work looks good) so I would guess your pre mix is a bit dry you might be able to flake it off with a putty knife but it will need to be removed. Pre mix separates when sitting on the shelf so it needs to be mixed in most cases and for texture I usually add a fair amount of water, for heavy knock down about a cup to a box, for spray knockdown 2 or more cups let it sit then knock down. So to get back on track remove the material that is cracking add some water to your mud and give it another try. Texture is a bit of an art and the amount of water varies with the conditions both humidity and temperature.

Comment: **No it is not a patch, I am covering up the walls in my bathroom (not tub) it was painted over wallpaper and looks like crap. I do not know what you mean by throwback. ( Just a House Wife ) The mud is thick. I hate to waste any thing and I would like to find a way to fix instead of tear down. Any suggestions?**

Comment: I never said throwback but if a painted surface it still needs to be clean, I have textured over paint many times but the surface needs to be roughed up a bit and clean. In my opinion a heavy knock down is a mistake in a bathroom because it will have more surface to hold moisture , mold and have many more problems than looking more ugly than the wall paper that is easily removed.

Comment: ** Okay so I was wrong in thinking that buying Semi-Gloss paint that repels against mold and moister was fine for the walls in my bathroom ? Is there another way to texture the walls in the bathroom without starting over and peeling the wallpaper that seems like a lot more work. I would like to do something different and not common. I am sorry it was Kick Back and not throwback. ( LOL)**

Comment: Wet it down and scrape it off. Strip the wallpaper if you can let it dry prime with flat oil based primer  the do your skip coating with mud let dry then paint 2 coats satin or egg shell sheen